# GitVersion only bump major version

Tags: gitversion

I'm using GitVersion to increment the minor version automatically on every merge to master. As such, my `GitVersion.yml` looks like this:

```
mode: Mainline
branches:
  master:
    increment: Minor
```

And this works fine. What I'm trying to do is allow people to bump the major version by including `next-version: x.0.0` at the root level and not changing anything else. If I add that to my current config, it bumps it to `x.1.0` because it's picking up the minor increment too.
Is there a way to configure it to do what I want?

Comment: Why not use the commit message functionality?
`+semver:major`

Comment: Trying to have as few manual steps as possible. The commit message is what I've gone with in the end.

Comment: Yeah but setting next version in GitVersion.yml require you to change that file every time you need to bump major. I'd prefer an extra line in my commit message or tag over that every day. In general, in my opinion bumping major should be a more conscious decision than bumping minor. Currently I prefer automatic patch increment on PR merge and use mainline mode for that.